# Render objects based on 1 specific object on the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm presently implementing a few features into a vector editor based off of `fabric.js` and have hit a bump in the road with how best to handle this scenario:

> In order to resize/scale the canvas smaller and larger via scaling grippies/controls, I've begun the task of implementing a "fake canvas" that stays in the middle of the real canvas (the real canvas is resized to fill it's DOM parent at all times. This presents several issues, the biggest being, dealing with objects on the canvas, ensuring their coordinate are always relative to my "fake canvas" (which is just a `Rect` with some restrictions applied, e.g. locking movement, rotation, etc).

So I'm really just looking for strategies/suggestions at how to go about doing this. For instance, I know I'd be dealing with newly added objects, moving objects and preventing them to be moved outside of the boundaries of my fake canvas. Among other considerations.

Thanks for the input and suggestions. I'm not looking for code, I'm more just looking for suggestions of how best to handle all the canvas related things, transferred to a fake canvas. I see that the Shutterstock Editor does some of this too, so I guess it doesn't seem like it's out of the realm of possibilities.

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb no sir, i'm making progress, but it's slow going. I'm mostly mimicking what has been done with the Shutterstock Editor, as they are doing exactly this, to really treat the canvas more like the Adobe Illustrator canvas (in how you interact with it, etc).